# Frequently installed macOS software that can be updated via the command line

Tags: osx, command-line, macos, shell-scripting, package-manager

What software / package managers are frequently installed on macOS that can be updated via the command line?

The software / package managers could either be included with macOS, or they could be software that many people (including myself) might have installed.

I'm writing a zsh script to update all such software on my machine, like:

- gem
- homebrew
- oh my zsh
- pip
- sdkman

I want to ensure that I'm not missing anything that can be updated.

I'm currently skipping updating cpan, because whenever I've tried, I get tons of errors. Are there any other command-line software updaters that frequently experiences errors while updating?

Are there any other package managers that I should use instead of one of the above?

I know that this contains multiple questions, but they're all related, so I figured it makes sense to group them together.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I see you refer to `homebrew` and `sdkman`, which already can keep packages (=software) up to date. Why do you want your own script to do the same?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Most of the time, you need to run multiple commands to update each single package manager.  Also, I can run one script that will update every package manager I use.  My current top level script calls 6 other scripts, each of which is 2 - 6 lines of code (besides shebangs & whitespace).  So, I can just run `update` instead of having to remember & retype 30 or so lines of code (which sometimes parses the responses of previous commands to be input for subsequent commands).

Answer (score 1):

Two other package managers are MacPorts and Fink.

Comment: Does this update everything you’ve used homebrew to install, or just homebrew itself?

Comment: @jmh I know how to update the software listed in my question (which includes hombrew), I just want to know what other software that might be on my machine can also be updated.  e.g., I didn't know that Oh My Zsh could be updated until recently, so I accidentally missed out on updating that.  Once I know what can be updated, I can read the relevant documentation to learn how to update it.